# ng-controller not working / using controller in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Working on an Ionic project using a folder by feature structure.

All of my JS files are combined into a single app.js in the www folder.

Outside of the www folder I have

```
app/
    feature/
        feature.html
        feature.js <-- controller
```

The feature.js looks like:

```
angular.module('app').controller('Feature', function(){
    console.log('Feature controller initiated');
});
```

In feature.html:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="Feature">

</ion-view>
```

And my app is setup with:

```
    angular.module('app', ['ionic']).run / .config etc.
```

The combined js file shows everything is collated including the controller, but no console log it output.

The app.js file is included correctly in the index file as the states are working and app config etc.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller declaration and utilisation are different:

```
<ion-view ng-controller="Metronome">
```

```
angular.module('app').controller('Feature', function(){
```

---

I think what you want is `ng-controller="Feature"`.

Comment: Sorry, was replacing naming for this example but in my app they are the same. I have updated my example.

Comment: @Lovelock Did you correctly import `feature.js` in `feature.html`?

Comment: Because all scripts are combined into the app.js file, that is included in the main index.html so I though that would be enough? feature.html is shown in the view inside <ion-nav-view>

Answer (score 0):

Error on my part for this issue.

I had two controllers in different folders that has the same name declaration.